# Ansible - adding parameters for rpm

Tags: ansible, rpm, yum

I am beginner using Ansible and I am using some rpm to be installed on my target machine with yum as the package manager. I am getting an error saying the package conflicts with some files on the system. When I saw for the error on the net, I found that adding the following parameter "--replacefiles" solves my problem.

But, I am not sure how to specify this parameter to the ansible playbook. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a package that is already installed? What package is this?

Comment: That package is not installed. I have some "abcd.rpm" (a software written locally) stored on my server and this needs to be installed on a newly launched machine. I have specified that yum is the package manager to be used.

Comment: Why is your package including files that some other package also includes? Do you want both your package and the system package installed? (That's what the file conflict warning is telling you and what that option allows to override.)

Comment: I get that completely, but I have no control over the generation of rpm's. I just know that there is a way to replace the existing files and I did that previously using "rpm --replacefiles" command. I just don't know how to do the same using yum as the package manager.

Comment: This is just a short term fix, but the long term fix is what you suggested. Removing the files which are already there.

Comment: Don't bother with this "fix" it isn't correct. *Especially* if the package that owns the files is some other package. Figure out which package owns those files and if you don't want/need it then remove it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not supported by the `yum` module. You will need to call yum per `shell` or `command` module to use it with that param.